# Calculate total of some fields in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table like this

```
item_id  item_quantity
----------------------
324      2

432      23

543      12

879      3
```

The `item_id` field is not auto-increment but it is unique.

The inputs of the query will be some `item_id` values and the result should be sum of those in `item_quantity`.

For instance, if the inputs are `324, 543`, then the query should return `14` (2 + 12)

Is it possible to do this at mysql level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is the sum of the `item_quantity`, all you need to do is:

```
Select  Sum(item_quantity)
From    Table
Where   item_id In (324, 543)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using in :

```
SELECT SUM(item_quantity)
FROM table
WHERE item_id in (324,543)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works on MSSQL, not sure about MySQL, though:

```
SELECT SUM(item_quantity) FROM MyTable WHERE item_id in (324, 543)
```

**EDIT:** OK, others got the same answer. So I guess it also works on MySQL.